# Reboot if a feature is installed or uninstalled

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In my installer I try to perform a reboot if a specific feature is installed or gets uninstalled.

```
<util:CloseApplication Id="CloseApp3" 
    Target="Explorer.exe" 
    RebootPrompt="yes"><![CDATA[&ExplorerAddIn=3 OR !ExplorerAddIn=3]]>
</util:CloseApplication>
```

For my understanding the above condition should trigger, if the Addin will be installed (`&`) or is currently present (`!`) which should also include uninstallation. (local => absend)

If the feature gets installed, it will reboot, but if the feature will uninstall the setup will not ask to reboot.

Comment: We need more basic information: Why is this reboot needed? What are you installing?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul The feature is intalling some parts that integrate with the explorer. So we reatert that everything is correctly loaded (and unloaded after remove of feature). From my understanding CloseApplication should show the reboot message if the target is running (which is normaly the case) and the condition enables the CloseApplication element. I understand the condition so that it will be true if the feature gets installed or is already instaled (including uninstallation). But that does not happen, so I think I don't understand the condition.